# DoS stress test not working

Tags: ddos, denial-of-service

First off I'd like to say this is my first post on StackExchange, so please let me know if there's anything wrong with it. Also, I don't know much about networking and I'm just making a simple java application (A packet listener with jnetpcap) to try to learn the basics.

I'm using Low Orbit Ion Cannon to flood myself.
I've managed to get upload speeds of 500 kB/sec but my upload doesn't peak far over 560 kB/sec (the same I have when I use lower settings with 100 kB/sec uploads) so I'm clearly not receiving close to all of the packets I'm sending. I've tried on a few ports, but none of them work. I don't think I have any ports forwarded on my router, but I thought that wasn't a problem because I was connecting to a computer on my LAN (the same computer I'm DoS'ing from actually)

I've tried disabling my firewall, but this didn't help at all. Am I wrong about not needing a port forwarded if I'm staying on my LAN network, or is there some other problem here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a specific tool.